# Can NER Stanford called in java file?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, pos-tagger

I've tried to give NER and POS tag from texts with [Stanford Named Entity Recognizer (NER)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) and [Stanford Log-linear Part-Of-Speech Tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml).

Let me give you an example of POStag

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

public class POSTag {
    static MaxentTagger tagger =  new MaxentTagger("english_language_pos.tagger");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String text = "Sarah and I go to Samsung office in Korea."
        String tagged = tagger.tagString(text);

        System.out.println(tagged);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Sarah_NNP and_CC I_PRP go_VBP to_TO Samsung_NNP office_NN in_IN Korea_NNP ._.
```

And for NER Stanford, I have to run in command line:

```
java -mx500m -cp stanford-ner-3.5.2.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier indonesian_language_ner.gz -textFile E:/file.txt > E:/file_ner.txt
```

My question is how can I call Stanford NER in file with java extension(file.java)? Is there any way to call Stanford NER besides from command line?
Or any other tool or library that I can use to give NER that called from java file?

*****edit:
I need the output of NER become like this:

```
Sarah_PERSON and_O I_O go_O to_O Samsung_ORGANIZATION office_O in_O Korea_PLACE ._O
```

*****edit

**fyi: I use Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    String model = "english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";
    String text = "file.txt";

    AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(model);
    classifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(text);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I need the output is text with tag NER. I have edit my post for detail.

Comment: This should work. The tagging is done with `/` by default, you could easily adapt to another character.

Comment: How can I write the output to file instead of print to console? There are other method classifyAndWriteAnswers with different parameter but I don't know which can used to write to file. Thanks

Comment: I found method classifyToString(String) that can be used to give NER tag without print to console, so I can save the tagged String in variable. For example: `String tagged = classifier.classifyToString("Sarah and I go to Samsung office in Korea.")`

Answer (score 1):

Since some of us might need the tagged-string and not just directly print to console, here is the code for the same:

```
public void doTagging(CRFClassifier model, String input) {
  input = input.trim();
  System.out.println(input + "=>"  +  model.classifyToString(input));
}
```

Hope this helps.

If you need full code on how to use Stanford NER in jave here is a good blog:

https://dataturks.com/blog/stanford-core-nlp-ner-training-java-example.php?s=so